# Should I write anything in the "Type of License/Certification/Permit OR Working Title" field when requesting a record clearance for visa application?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, california, criminal-records

I am a French citizen, US permanent resident, California resident and currently located in California, US. I am applying for some visa: the visa application requires a letter of verification stating that the applicant has no criminal record, which must be issued from a US state or Federal Bureau of Investigation. In my case I believe this means I have to request a record clearance from the California DOJ (Department of Justice) for visa/Iimigration purposes on
https://oag.ca.gov/fingerprints/visaimmigration

On the Request Form ([Request Visa/Immigration - Form BCIA 8016 VISA (Live Scan), pdf](https://oag.ca.gov/sites/all/files/agweb/pdfs/fingerprints/forms/bcia-8016-visa.pdf?)), am I supposed to write anything in the "Type of License/Certification/Permit OR Working Title", and if so, what? Record clearance? I am confused if that's a Type of License/Certification, or whether submitting the form already means that I request a record clearance or that the "Type of License/Certification/Permit OR Working Title" is optional for some kind of special requests.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an instruction guide on the page I think you intended to link.

https://oag.ca.gov/sites/all/files/agweb/pdfs/fingerprints/forms/fingerprinting_visa_immigration_info.pdf

It says for *Type of License/Certification/Permit OR Working Title*: Write a brief explanation of why you
need a copy of your criminal history
record; and for examples: "Work
Visa, Student Visa, Immigration,
Letter of Good Conduct, Police
Certificate, or Citizenship."